# Reading XML Xpath only when xpath is defined in Ansible

Tags: xml, unix, xpath, ansible, devops

I am trying to execute a ansible task of reading a xpath from xml only if the xpath is present

```
  - Read xml
    xml:
       path: /home/myuser/myfile.xml
       xpath: /component/releases/release[@version='1.3']/scripts/script
       content: attribute
       attribute: path
    register: scriptVal
```

and my xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component name="anthony_db" ....... >
  <releases>
    <release version="1.2">
      <scripts>
        <script path="/path/to/scripts/sql1" />
        <script path="/path/to/scripts/sql2" />
      </scripts>
    </release>
    <release version="1.3">
      <scripts> 
      </scripts>
    </release>
  </releases>
</component>
```

Now my Ansible task correctly read when I pass version 1.2 but when I pass version 1.3 it fails because scripts attribute doesn't exist how can i put a check in when condition so that it reads only when scripts attribute exists.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a [block/rescue construct](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) to handle the case when the task fails. Here's a POC you can play changing the version to see result:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: version
      prompt: "Version ?"
      default: "1.2"
      private: no

  vars:
    xml: |-
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <component name="anthony_db">
        <releases>
          <release version="1.2">
            <scripts>
              <script path="/path/to/scripts/sql1" />
              <script path="/path/to/scripts/sql2" />
            </scripts>
          </release>
          <release version="1.3">
            <scripts>
            </scripts>
          </release>
        </releases>
      </component>

  tasks:
    - block:

        - name: Read xml
          xml:
            xmlstring: "{{ xml }}"
            xpath: "/component/releases/release[@version='{{ version }}']/scripts/script"
            content: attribute
          register: scriptVal

      rescue:

        - debug:
            msg: "There is no script for version {{ version }}"

        - set_fact:
            scriptVal: "I have no value"

    - name: Show value of scriptVal
      debug:
        var: scriptVal
```

Comment: but will rescue allow me to continue the next tasks after read xml?

Comment: You should click on the documentation link I provided for your convenience which explain all this. Meanwhile I adapted my example to make this more obvious.